# Listing contents of a AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have multiples aws accounts and want to list of the buckets contents for the multiples S3 buckets from multiple account , can any one have any possible script ?? using boto3 or awswrangler

I am trying to list the content of S3 .

Comment: As a starting point, are you able to list the contents of a _single_ bucket? It would then be a matter of list the contents of _several_ buckets. Please note that when you wish to access buckets belonging to a different AWS Account, you will either need a Bucket Policy on the bucket that permits access by your credentials, or you would need to use credentials from the AWS Account that owns the bucket.

Answer (score 3):

You can use python and boto3 to list objects inside of an s3 bucket. Here is an example from the Boto3 Docs page we can use as as our base.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#id228

> The following example shows how to use an Amazon S3 bucket resource to list the objects in the bucket.
>
> ```py
> import boto3
>
> s3 = boto3.resource('s3') # create your boto3 s3 client
> bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket') # load the bucket
> for obj in bucket.objects.all(): # for each object in your s3 bucket
>   print(obj.key) # print key (filepath)
> ```

To get started, I would first create a dictionary object with the keys initialized as the name of the buckets you are wanting to get the contents for.

```
buckets_files_dictionary = {
  'mybucketname': [], 
  'mybucketname2': [], 
  'mybucketname3': []
}
```

I would then use the bucket names to load each s3 content listings individually.

```
for bucket_name in buckets_files_dictionary.keys():
```

Load the bucket client using boto

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
```

loop through the objects within:

```
for bucket_file in bucket.objects.all():
```

Append the file names to the dictionary

```
buckets_files_dictionary[bucket_name].append(bucket_file.key)
```

at the end of your script you can either access the files by bucket name to get a file listing: `print(buckets_files_dictionary['mybucket'])` or print the entire object `print(buckets_files_dictionary)`

putting it all together:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3') # create your boto3 s3 client

buckets_files_dictionary = {
  'mybucketname': [], 
  'mybucketname2': [], 
  'mybucketname3': []
}

for bucket_name in buckets_files_dictionary.keys():
  bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
  for bucket_file in bucket.objects.all():
    buckets_files_dictionary[bucket_name].append(bucket_file.key)

  print(f"{bucket_name}: {buckets_files_dictionary[bucket_name]}")
```

Hope this was useful, or at least gives you some inspiration to go off of as a starting point in using boto3. I would recommend taking a look at some of their other code samples on their documentation as well. They have a lot of great examples.